# How to used 2nd CSS file

Tags: css

How to use 2nd CSS file on my WordPress website ?

Here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" 
      href="http://www.mydomain.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/style.css" >
```

But I need to extra CSS file with seam themes. Now I am how to connect my new CSS file? Please anybody help me.

Comment: Just include the css file in the `head` or using `wp_enqueue_style` from `functions.php` file.

Comment: What is your problem ? Don't you know how to add stylesheet / or you need `css` specific help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many css files as you like. The attributes that are loaded from the last css file will override attributes of any previously declared and conflicting attributes but you can specify them in as many files as you like. You can "connect" or link you new css file in your html using this :

---

Looks like you needed it for wordpress themes.

1. You need to have one main style.css file. You have to include it by using  type="text/css"/>. Once this is done you can add additional css files by doing something like this: /address-to-css-file.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />. bloginfo('template_directory') is a function which prints out the directory of your template.
2. You can also use @import in your main stylesheet (style.css) . Add these lines:
   @imports url('link to css');
3. Or you can use 
   http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style this link has a description of how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use that  exact code and duplicate it as much as you want.

Just change the `href` to each new file name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware that any changes made to the theme will be erased if the theme is updated.

I suggest you read up on FTP and upload the CSS files in the CSS folder for your theme. You need to know where the CSS's location is for it to be called effectively.

Once you have uploaded the CSS file to the theme's folder, do the following:

In WordPress administration, click on the left side menu item `Appearance`, then click on the sub-menu item `Editor`. You will see on the right hand side a whole lot of links show up. Click on the `header.php` link.

In the `header.php` file, you'll notice a section that starts with `<head>`. Enter the path to where your CSS file is located on the server like so:

```
<LINK href="link/to/your/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Click on the `Update File` button on the bottom of the page. Verify your work.